# Castle DynamicProxy: create a new property with a custom attribute for XML serialization

Tags: c#, xml, proxy, castle-dynamicproxy

I have a situation where I have some DTO classes that should be implemented like:

```
public class City
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public State State { get; set; }
}

public class State
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is, these are actually DTO classes for REST XML resources.  And the City resource may include the State resource inline, or it may simply provide the resource ID (a URI).  I am handling access to the DTO via the Repository pattern and would like it to be transparent to clients whether State is lazy loaded or not (like how NHibernate does with it's entity classes).

So my current plan is to use Castle `DynamicProxy` to create a proxy object when the REST Repository detects that the class isn't fully "hydrated" (i.e. not everything is inline).  The proxy object will know how to lazy load attributes as needed.

To actually implement this, however, the only thing I've come up with is to have backing attributes for all relationships and put the Xml attributes on those.  So the strategy looks like this:

```
[XmlType]
public class City
{
  [XmlElement]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [ToOneRestRelationship(BackingPropertyName = "StateBacking")]
  public State State { get; set; }

  [XmlElement(Name = "state")]
  public ResourceBase StateBacking { get; set; }
}

[XmlType]
public class State
{
  [XmlElement]
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then the Repository object knows to set up the proxy object to either get the object from the `StateBacking` property and use that (inlined resource case) or do a REST request to lazily retrieve the `State` object (resource URI case, i.e. lazy) from the ID specified in the backing property.

**Question**

The issue is, this backing field is pretty ugly.  What I would like is a way to have Castle generate a class that would have the backing property *with the `XmlElement` attribute applied* that I could pass to the `XmlSerializer`.  Then my DTO classes could look more like the first example and wouldn't have to be aware that the actual serialising class has a backing property.

Is something like this possible with Castle or any other Proxy library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going an interesting and completely wrong way, i think it is indeed possible to create a backing field that won't be seen by clients. Since proxying works by inheriting from the proxied class, any property on the derived class won't be seen in the scope of the original class. So mixins are the way to go:

Given Foo

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual string  Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Bar bar { get; set; }
}
```

and Bar

```
public class Bar
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

We can declare an interface that will let us retrieve the backing field and an implementation

```
public interface IHasBarBackingField
{
    Bar RetrieveBar();
}

public class HasBarBackingField : IHasBarBackingField
{
    public HasBarBackingField()
    {
        // the constructor must contain ways to resolve the bar. Since
        // the class is built while proxying you should have all the data
        // available at this moment
    }

    public Bar RetrieveBar()
    {
        return new Bar(); // example, you could have a backing field somewhere in this class
    }
}
```

Then you just have to mixin both classes when proxying:

```
var pg = new ProxyGenerator();

var hasBarBackingField = new HasBarBackingField();

var options = new ProxyGenerationOptions();
options.AddMixinInstance(hasBarBackingField);
var test = pg.CreateClassProxy<Foo>(options, new BarInterceptor());
```

and intercept the call interesting you in order to return the backing Bar

```
public class BarInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        if (invocation.Method.Name == "get_bar")
        {
            var hasBarBackingField = invocation.InvocationTarget as IHasBarBackingField;
            invocation.ReturnValue = hasBarBackingField.RetrieveBar();
        }
        else
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
        }
    }
}
```

The HasBarBackingField class should be built to return either the direct object or retrieve the referenced REST object. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Based on what i've seen NSubstitute do i'd say it is possible, as long as your properties are virtual: http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/partial-subs/ . 
Creating a `City` class with virtual property State that is then resolved at runtime using the substitution pattern should be feasable

```
public class City
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [StateId(10)]
  public virtual State State { get; set; }
}

var sCity = Substitute.For<City>();
sCity.State.Returns((core) => {return null; // here you can access informations about the call});
```

Definitely doable, but it's *terra incognita* from here on!

Comment: Well, the issue by doing it this way is that State has to return a State, I couldn't return something higher up in the object hierarchy with this.  Which is why I wouldn't to use a completely different property.  I'm also concerned about how I will get a static attribute assigned to this new property.

Comment: The State property would return a state, unless i don't understand your remark it's possible to do something like sCity.State.Returns((core) => {return GetState(GetStateId()); // Get State Id would be a method to retrieve the attribute value })

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  Yes, doing a proxy on State is easy and I'm already doing that.  The issue is, the State proxy works by checking another property.  That's a property that the repository needs but the DTO actually doesn't (the backing property above).  I'd rather not have the backing property in the DTO but to remove it I would have to have a way to generate it some how.  That is, I need a way to generate a new property that didn't exist on the class that I'm making a proxy for.

Comment: Can't you create a separate entity to hold the backing property value? Or simply use caching in order to benefit from its sliding expiration and reference a key from the State proxy?

Comment: Well, I suppose I could make a Castle Mixin where my extra "properties" were just an array of all the backing properties.  But I would still have a problem with XML serialisation.  The issue is, XmlSerializer looks for XmlElement, etc. as attributes on the properties of the class it's serialising.  I would need some way to get the XmlSerializer to see my proxy-only methods and read attributes from them.

Comment: From what i understand your classes are serialized on the server. Couldn't you create classes heriting from the POCO object that will manage the backing fields. When deserializing them you could cast them as the root object in order to "hide" the backing fields for the client?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49665/discussion-between-samy-and-jason)