# Creating a Class from Another Class in C# via Roslyn

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have a .NET Core C# app that is referencing several third-party libraries. Each of these libraries has an object that I need to use in my app. There's one catch, my database has two properties associated with each of the properties in each of the classes I need in the third-party libraries. Those two properties are `Name` and `Description`.

In an ideal world, each of these third-party libraries would use *my* base class that has `Name` and `Description` :). Since that's not going to happen, I was wondering if there was a way in .NET Core to dynamically create a new type, and add properties from another type using Reflection.

I've seen examples of creating a new type via Roslyn using a string of Text. However, I don't want to use a string of text. I'd rather define a type using pure code. Then, I'd like to use Reflection to 1) get this list of the properties on the third-party class and 2) add them to my new type.

I know how to get a list of properties from a Type using Reflection. However, I'm not sure how to use Rosalyn to 1) Create a new type and 2) add new properties to that type. Is that even possible in the .NET Core world? I know it was in .NET pre-.NET Core days. But, I can't seem to figure out how to do it in .NET Core.

Comment: Roslyn is c# compiler. I think you are mistaking its purpose with reflection.

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Do you want to "create" the type at runtime with reflection or do you want to create the new type at build time with Roslyn?

Comment: What you want is Reflection Emit or maybe some library like Castle Core to dynamically mix interfaces?

Comment: @R1PFake - I want to "create" the type at runtime. Basically, I want to clone one of the third-party types to a new type that incudes my two properties at runtime.

Comment: @RicardoAlves - I looked into `Reflection.Emit`.From my understanding though, it doesn't have the necessary methods at this time to let me dynamically create a type at runtime. I basically want to clone one of the third-party types to a new type that includes my two properties at runtime.

Comment: @user687554 You can do that with reflection Emit, but I think what you want is to use Castle Core. With Castle Core you can instantiate an object of the third party library, and mix-in you interface if you want.

Comment: I think this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22377908/castle-dynamicproxy-create-a-new-property-with-a-custom-attribute-for-xml-seria

Comment: @RicardoAlves - How do you do it with `Reflection.Emit` in .NET Core?

Comment: @user687554 I never did it in Asp.net Core, but I think you can do it from what I searched. But I think it may be an overkill for you as you can use Castle Core instead (it uses Reflection Emit internally)

Comment: Why do you need to do this dynamically? Don't you know the types of the third party classes at compile time? Seems to me you just need to subclass them.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this third party class:

```
class SomeThirdPartyClass
{
    public object Foo { get; set; }
    public object Bar { get; set; }
}
```

If you need to add properties, just subclass it and add them:

```
class MyClass : SomeThirdPartyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

//Example use
var o = new MyClass();
o.Name = "Name";           //Custom property
o.Foo = new object();      //Base property
```

If the third party class is [sealed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sealed), you can wrap it instead.

```
class MyClass<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public T Item { get; set; }
}

//Example use
var o = new MyClass<SomeThirdPartyClass>
{
    Item = new SomeThirdPartyClass()
};
o.Name = "name";            //Custom property
o.Item.Foo = new object();  //Base property
```